# Numbers question HCF

Tags: elementary-number-theory

P is a positive integer such that it is less than 400. Given that 15 is the Highest common factor of 45 and p , find two possible values of p.

This type of my question is my biggest problem . Can I get help or a hint for this question ? What is the concept related to these ? Thanks in advance

Comment: Think about how the $\gcd$ (greater common divisor, which is the same as highest common factor) of two numbers relate to their prime factorization.

Comment: Well, $p=15$ works. Can you think of a few others?

Answer (score 4):

We can see pretty quickly that $p = 15$ is one of the answers. Another option that is
available is $p = 30.$ We can see that $15 \mid 30 \wedge 15 \mid 45$, but it
is apparent that if we look for a divisor
$15 < d \leq 30$, we can show sequentially that if $d < 30$, each of these values does
not divide $30$, and if $d = 30$, $d$ does not divide $45$. Thus $p = 30$ is another
option.